# Onclick event; If and Else

Tags: javascript, html

All right so I am doing a javascript code for a login type form and it will lead you to a new page. Here it is:

```
function submit1()
{
    var x=document.getElementById("username");
    var y=document.getElementById("password");
    if (x.value=="username" && y.value=="password")
    {
        window.location="Example.php";
    }
    else
    {
        window.alert=("The information you have submitted is incorrect and needs to be submitted again!");
    }
}
```

When ever I am hitting the submit button it takes me straight to the page instead of checking to see if it right. Please help!
Thank you in advanced! ***To let you know this is not a permanet login page!***

Comment: Be careful : Replace `window.alert=(` with `window.alert(`

Comment: w3school stuff I guess LOL

Comment: if you want a proper answer please include how you're calling this function. checking credentials in the client is Bad. are you using onSubmit if so your method needs to return false.

Comment: What I'm getting at is that we have no idea what you're actually telling the form to do without seeing at least the form start element and the submit button. If you have action filled in on the form and hit submit, it's going to GET/POST to that path.

Comment: @ally that's what I was get getting at too.

Answer (score 3):

The easy way to do this would be to use a `button` input:

```
<input type="button" value="Check" onclick = "submit1();" />
```

The alternative is to prevent this default behavior of a `submit` type input, by making the handler return `false`. Your HTML would look like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Check" onclick = "return submit1();" />
```

Your function would need to be changed a well (considering the fact that you want it to *not* redirect). I am assuming you want to preserve data entered, so I am not going to use `window.location` to redirect. Instead, I am going to allow the form to be submitted:

```
function submit1()
{
    var x=document.getElementById("username");
    var y=document.getElementById("password");
    if (x.value == "username" && y.value == "password") {
        window.alert=("The information you have submitted is incorrect and needs to be submitted again!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you can use the submit and then cancel the event. Helps to make it `no script` friendly :)

Comment: Now I have another problem. Now when I type in the incorrect stuff it takes me to the page of Example.php

Comment: @justnS I would need to see how the handler is being bound to demonstrate how to cancel the event.

Comment: @Wes I'm not sure what that means. Do you mean I should bind to the submit handler?

Comment: Damon auto correct. problem resolved in your edits. removing old comments.

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Login page
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms;text-align="center";font-size:20pt;
color:#00FF00;>
Simple Login Page
</h1>
<form name="login">
Username<input type="text" name="userid"/>
Password<input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
<input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
<input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
</form>
<script language="javascript">
function check(form)/*function to check userid & password*/
{
 /*the following code checkes whether the entered userid and password are matching*/
 if(form.userid.value == "myuserid" && form.pswrd.value == "mypswrd")
  {
     window.location="Example.php"; /*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
  }
 else
 {
   alert("Error Password or Username")/*displays error message*/
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The event needs to cancel the default event and return false. This will prevent the form from submitting.

HOWEVER, it should be a non-issue if the form submits anyway, because JavaScript CANNOT be trusted and therefore you MUST validate all input server-side.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="post" action="." id="myform">
 <!-- form contents --->
</form>    
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
    var f = document.getElementById('myform'), // get your form element
        x = document.getElementById('username'),
        y = document.getElementById('password'),
        handler;
    handler = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // stop submit
        if (x.value=='username' && y.value=='password') {
            window.location = 'Example.php';
        } else {
            window.alert('The information...');
        }
    };
    // listen to submit event
    if ('addEventListener' in f) {
        f.addEventListener('submit', handler, false);
    } else { // handle also IE...
        f.attachEvent('submit', function () {
            handler(window.event);
        });
    }
}());
</script>
```

**anyway it looks like you're trying to check login/password from JS what is not greatest idea (anyone can just look into source and read it)**

Comment: Why do you check if `window` has `addEventListener` when you only call it on the FORM element `f`?  Why not check if `f` has it?

Comment: its more generic, anyway you can check it on `f` as well

Comment: more generic might not mean better.  It would be a strange scenario, but if someone had removed `addEventListener` specifically from `window` but not from the form element prototype (or wherever it's stored) your code would fail, where it would still work if you checked on the form element instead.  I would argue that it's also cleaner, more readable code.

Comment: pretty strange scenario that someone would remove it from window, but here you have, I made edit. (also I'm not sure if any browser will allow you to remove it, on safari for example you can only replace with other function).

Comment: Yeah I am just trying this out. I am fairly new to JS and seeing if it could help with other stuff needed later